# NIFI AWS BATCHIQ PAAS

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi

I have a template which uses a keystore. locally, i just point it to my folder and it works. On the cloud, it doesnt seem to be working. i placed the keystore (jks) object under home/ec2-user/FUTBIN.jks . i did chmod777 on home , home/ec2-user and home/ec2-user/FUTBIN.jks .

I also placed the keystore on AWS S3 which has the same symptoms. Uploading the sql JDBC driver on S3 works without any problem

Please find screenshot attached of nifi controller config and error

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you are running NiFi on a Linux file system, I believe you need a leading slash ('/') to indicate an absolute path from the root of the file system, like `/home/ec2-user/FUTBIN.jks`.  Without the leading slash for the root, it is interpreted relative to the NiFi process directory.

Comment: Already tried that, nothing so far. Could it be because the truststore / keystore was generated on another machine?

Answer (score 0):

Changing directory to /opt/ worked correctly.